# metafor() non-negative sampling variance

Tags: variance

I am trying to learn meta regression using the metafor() package. In running
one of the mixed regression models, I received an error indicating

"There are outcomes with non-positive sampling variances."

I am at lost as to how to proceed with this error. I understand that certain
model statistics (e.g., I^2 and QE) cannot be computed with due to the
presence of non-positive sampling variances. However, I am not sure whether
these results can be interpreted similarly as we would have otherwise. I
also tried using other estimators and/or the unweighted option; the error
still persists.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to clarify: You are getting a *warning*, not an *error*.

Aside from that, I can't think of many situations where it is reasonable to assume that the sampling variance is really equal to 0 in a particular study. I would first question whether this really makes sense. This is why the `rma()` function is generating this warning message -- to make the user aware of this situation and question whether this really is intended/reasonable.

But suppose that we really want to go through with this, then you have to use an estimator for tau^2 that can handle this (e.g., `method="REML"` -- which is actually the default). If the estimate of tau^2 ends up equal to 0 as well, then the model cannot be fitted at all (due to division by zero -- and then you get an *error*). If you do end up with a positive estimate of tau^2, then the results should be okay (but things like the Q-test, I^2, or H^2 cannot be computed then).